# Graphx lookup vertexLabel from vertexID

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hash, lookup, spark-graphx

I have created a graph from apache spark graphx with vertices in the form 
(vertexId,vertexLabel)

```
graph.vertices.take(5)
(73607571123990017,157.55.145.210)
(-8476294060085646488,65.55.116.184)
(-1290863642671546500,184.73.235.12)
(4333023396065188982,63.91.215.17)
(-8653425046038876102,23.62.195.78)
```

I have calculated single source shortest paths from a vertex with syntax and output like below

```
(dstID,(length,List(whole path))

sssp.vertices.take(5)
(-912545243459764830,(3,List(223277346867836574, -7175187973700249964, 3342971904799511809, -912545243459764830)))
(2186653685768931954,(1000,List()))
(-5644725372565726221,(1000,List()))
(4398516124184853312,(3,List(223277346867836574, -7175187973700249964, 3342971904799511809, 4398516124184853312)))
(-7175187973700249964,(1,List(223277346867836574, -7175187973700249964)))
```

I wanted to lookup the vertexLabel (e.g 157.55.145.210) from vertexId 
 (e.g 73607571123990017) such the output of `sssp.vertices.take(5)` becomes like below

```
(145.22.33.456,(3,List(155.22.32.938, 185.42.53.756, 105.62.83.956, 125.26.73.656)))
```

I have tried somethiing like this but it only works one single vertexId not for the whole output of `sssp.vertices.take(5)`

```
graph.vertices.filter{case(id, _) => id==223277346867836574L}.collect
```

What should be my approach to have the output of shortest path in the manner showed above?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to perform joins with the original graph to get back the label.
I'd flatMap all the path into one giant RDD and do a single join to get the label. Vertices with empty path should be handled separatedly with another join.

```
val pathsRDD = sssp.vertices.values.flatMap { case (_, vertices) =>
  if (vertices.isEmpty) {
    Seq.Empty
  } else {
    val dest = vertices.last
    // Store an index so we can reconstruct the list in the correct order
    vertices.zipWithIndex.map { case (v, index) => 
      (v, (dest, index))
    }
  }
}

pathsRDD.join(graph.vertices).map { case (vertex, ((dest, index), label)) =>
  (dest, (label, index)) 
}.groupByKey.map { case (dest, iter) =>
  val out = iter.toList.sortBy(_._2).map(_._1)
  (out.last, (out.size, out))
}
```